# fetch Data cursor without clearing it

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-cursor

Working on oracle DB and used a sysrefcursor. I need to fetch one value from cursor. But whenever we use

```
FETCH p_cursor INTO variable;
```

it completely clears out all the data from cursor. I need this cursor in the procedure. Could any one please tell me the procedure of fetching the data from cursor without clearing it.

Comment: fetch into a different variable?

Comment: What does "clear out" mean?  A cursor is a forward-only structure.  Once you fetch a row, you can't go back.  I'd start with asking what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Clear out means empty the cursor..

Comment: You can, for example, fetch it to INDEX BY TABLE and use this structure instead of cursor